# How to get the stored email content(not only subject)

Tags: mailgun

there

I meet a problem how to get the email contents from mailgun api.

I use the mailgun event api (https://documentation.mailgun.com/user_manual.html#events) and i get the event logs successfully.

The return data like that

```
{
 "items": [
{
  "tags": [],
  "timestamp": 1376325780.160809,
  "envelope": {
    "sender": "me@samples.mailgun.org",
    "transport": ""
  },
  "event": "accepted",
  "campaigns": [],
  "user-variables": {},
  "flags": {
    "is-authenticated": true,
    "is-test-mode": false
  },
  "message": {
    "headers": {
      "to": "user@example.com",
      "message-id": "20130812164300.28108.52546@samples.mailgun.org",
      "from": "Excited User <me@samples.mailgun.org>",
      "subject": "Hello"
    },
    "attachments": [],
    "recipients": [
      "user@example.com"
    ],
    "size": 69
  },
  "recipient": "user@example.com",
  "method": "http"
 }
 ],
 "paging": {
 "next":
    "https://api.mailgun.net/v3/samples.mailgun.org/events/W3siY...",
 "previous":
     "https://api.mailgun.net/v3/samples.mailgun.org/events/Lkawm..."
 }
}
```

But the problem is that the events logs were not contains the email content(only subject,from,to...).

How can i get the email contents?

Can somebody provided me an example?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The mailgun Log API does not contain the email contents.

To get the email contents, you need to register a webhook and follow the [Retrieving Stored Messages](https://documentation.mailgun.com/api-sending.html#retrieving-stored-messages) example.

You can also get the messages through the Events API according to this [blog post](http://blog.mailgun.com/how-to-view-your-messages/).

Comment: Thanks for you reply. I got the answer from this blog. http://blog.mailgun.com/how-to-view-your-messages/

Answer (score 0):

Follow the instruction of https://www.mailgun.com/blog/how-to-view-your-messages.

1. Use [Event API](https://documentation.mailgun.com/en/latest/api-events.html) to get `storage.url` of each mail.
2. `GET` the url, you will have message body in `stripped-html`.

But as the time of writing. You have to use "Private API Key" as the password. It can be found in Security panel of your mailgun account page.

Comment: Add the relevant content from your link to the body of your post.